# npx install error for create react folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

> i type this npx code

npx create-react-app movie-app-2020

> then show this error

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.16.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

- web-vitals@1.1.2
- @testing-library/jest-dom@5.15.0
- @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
- @testing-library/react@11.2.7
  added 43 packages from 86 contributors and audited 1919 packages in 10.487s

154 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 13 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.16.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

removed 1 package and audited 1918 packages in 5.704s

154 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 13 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Created git commit.

Success! Created movie-app-2020 at /Users/hwangchangmin/Documents/movie-app-2020
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save-dev xxxxx
# Eg
npm install --save-dev tslint@^5.0.0
```